# Centralizing exceptions from asynchronous tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, exception, task-parallel-library

I implemented a custom `HandleErrorAttribute` in my MVC application and it's been working great to somehow centralize and catch ALL the exceptions that occur in the application.

```
public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Problem is: I've started to implement some async tasks, like this one:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomethingAsync());
```

And realized that my `CustomHandleErrorAttribute` is not intercepting the exceptions that happen in those methods: in this case, if an exception takes place inside the `DomeSomethingAsync()` method, then my `HandleErrorAttribute` won't catch it; and `Global.asax` wont either.

What's a good implementation for centralizing exceptions that occur in asynchronous tasks? I don't want to implement a simple try/catch block in every method: I want to count with some kind of handler that captures them.

Comment: What do you get when you invoke it like `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomethingAsync());`

Comment: @EZI That bubbles the exception to the main thread. I don't want that. I want the async task to run anyhow and the main thread to ignore what the result of the async task is.

Comment: Does this help? http://dotnetcodr.com/2014/02/18/exception-handling-in-the-net-task-parallel-library-with-c-a-safety-catch-all/

Comment: Fire-and-forget is bad pattern, but if this is what you are looking for there as several existing duplicates. Otherwise i3arnon's answer provides good guidance. Please comment on whether fire-and-forget is what you are looking for.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I wanted a mechanism to actually capture all exceptions from the Fire-and-forget methods in a common handling class. But you're right: i3arnon gave a good approach ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way is to not use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, especially not on async methods.

Simply invoke the async method directly and await the returned task. Exceptions in that task will be rethrown and handled by the same mechanism as all your other exceptions:

```
await DoSomethingAsync();
```

`Task.Factory.StartNew` is useful for offloading work to a a `ThreadPool` thread, however you're already on a `ThreadPool` thread so this isn't needed.

If you want to abandon that task, you should realize nothing guarantees it would continue running. The application pool can be recycled while the task is running because nothing waits for it.

If you want to do *"fire and forget"* in asp.net you should use something like HangFire (more in [Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html))

---

In the world outside asp.net you can simply add a handler as a continuation using `ContinueWith` with `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` to make sure it only runs if there were exceptions, for example with an extension method:

```
public static void HandleExceptions(this Task task)
{
    task.ContinueWith(
        faultedTask => HandleException(faultedTask.Exception),
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
DoSomethingAsync().HandleExceptions();
```

Comment: That bubbles the exception to the main thread. I don't want that. I want the async task to run anyhow and the main thread to ignore what the result of the async task is.

Comment: @Silvestre Then how would you know the task even completed?

Comment: as the main thread (in my case, a Controller with an Action that does many things - the async task among them) is not relevant: now, from the application global perspective: I want to be able to intercept any possible exception in the async thread. But you may be right with nothing guaranteeing the continuity of the async task.... but for now, I'll focus on the exception catching.

Comment: @Silvestre the point is that if you abandon these tasks you could get an exception that won't have the chance to catch. But everything is in the answer.

Comment: Just tested it: that's a good approach for now: I'll set the **HandleExceptions** extension to my async tasks.
Thank you!